# Изменение вида даты короткого формата

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть дата такого вида:

```
05/30/2019 12:00
```

Как самым простым путем её превратить в такой вид:

```
30.05.2019 12:00
```

У меня были мысли обрезать текст простыми функциями выделив день, месяц и т.д., но, может есть более простой и "красивый" способ поменять местами 4 цифры и заменить 2 символа. Спасибо!

Comment: `'05/30/2019 12:00'.replace(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})$/, '$2.$1.$3 $4:$5')`

Comment: @АндрейNOP на кой 5 групп описывать, если первых двух достаточно?

Comment: @teran, написал полную регулярку, по которой и test можно сделать. Но вообще – да, если строка заведомо будет в нужном формате то можно и сократить. Но лучше, все же, работать со специализированными типами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```js
console.log(moment("05/30/2019 12:00", "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm").format("DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ради одной функции библиотеку тащить?

Comment: А у автора точно в одном месте надо с датой-временем работать? Я лишь предложил вариант, автор вправе выбрать любой из ответов или вообще никакой.

Comment: Спасибо, в моем случае библиотека и правда подключена, решение оказалась очень кстати. Странно, что я за него сразу не подумал. Правда все же интересно, есть ли варианты какие-нить в чистом виде. Даже на словах, без примеров.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev, можно регулярками, но зачем? Читаемость будет хуже. Раз уж библиотека используется уже, то я бы остановился на этом варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Если подойдет, то можно и так

```js
const date = new Date('05/30/2019 12:00');
const w = date.toLocaleString('ru');
const d = w.slice(0,w.length-3);
console.log( d.replace(',', ''))
```